# js variable 'undefined' in IE (value was set by ajax response)

Tags: php, javascript, variables, jquery

I've got a form that posts input to a php script (via ajax) onChange, and the script responds by setting a variable equal to true or false (based on some evaluation). Then when the form on the original page is submitted, that true/false variable is sent to a different php script.

However, in IE(9) when I submit the form, I get a debugging error saying `'eligible' is undefined`.

```
## PHP (data processor — php script 1)
if ( $disqualified ) echo '<script type="text/javascript">var eligible = false;</script>';
else echo '<script type="text/javascript">var eligible = true;</script>';

## JavaScript
$.ajax({
url: 'pageprocessor.php', // php script 2
type: "POST",
data: ({
    key: '<?php echo $key; ?>',
    group: '<?php echo $group; ?>',
    eligibility: eligible,
// eligible is set by the response from PHP above
// before this is executed (I'm sure of the order).
    current_page: page,
    cumulative_count: count,
    cumulative_total: total,
    cumulative_progress: progress
}),
```

<s>On a related note, when `eligible` is passed to php, it's value registers as text instead of boolean. Is there a way to fix that?</s> (use `1`/`0` instead of `true`/`false` via [PeeHaa's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285464/js-variable-undefined-in-ie-value-was-set-by-ajax-response#comment11708913_9285464))

**Work Around:** Use php's superglobal [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) variable to transfer `eligible`'s value from one script to the other.

Comment: "it's value registers as text instead of boolean." Request parameters are always strings

Comment: Is there some PHP thing that will allow me to specify that a value is boolean? something like `$eligible = BOOL($_Post['eligibility']);` ?

Comment: Why not simply use `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`?

Comment: omg—duh. thanks for that. any idea about the IE issue?

Comment: I wouldn't set the `eligable` variable that way. But I would rather add it to a data attribute of an element. The form for example. So that you can simply do the following in your jQuery: `eligibility: form.data('eligible'),`

Comment: sorry, I mistaken your code, don't worry :)

Comment: @PeeHaa um…what? data attribute? I just did a quick google of "form data attribute" and got a lot of junk a couple possibles, but they were kind of varied :/

Comment: instead of using eligible as variable name, have you tried renaming it to something else see if it works? also using "1" or "0" is easier than "true"/"false" you can use use if empty()

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is something like (untested):

HTML/PHP

```
<?php
$eligible = 1;
if ($disqualified) {
    $eligible = 0;
}
?>

<form action="pageprocessor.php" data-eligible="<?php echo $eligible; ?>">
  <select name="something">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="option1">Option1</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var form = $('form'); // you will need a better (more narrow) selector though

$.ajax({
url: form.attr('action'),
type: "POST",
data: ({
    key: '<?php echo $key; ?>',
    group: '<?php echo $group; ?>',
    eligibility: form.data('eligible'), // you still have to verify this server side!
    current_page: page,
    cumulative_count: count,
    cumulative_total: total,
    cumulative_progress: progress
}),
```

Comment: could `data-eligible="…"` be set via javascript in a response to AJAX? (the value of `eligible` is determined by an external script)

Comment: Sure you could simply do the following in the callback of the AJAX call: `form.data('eligible', 1)`

Comment: Oh, `data-` attributes are an HTML5 thing: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Comment: According to jQuery, this won't work in IE: http://api.jquery.com/data/ (see "Additional Notes")

Comment: I just tried it, and it works in Ffx but in IE `alert('eligible = ' + $("#survey").data("eligible"));` returns `eligible = undefined` (the php is `if ( $disqualified ) echo '<script type="text/javascript"> $("#survey").data("eligible",0); </script>'; else echo '<script type="text/javascript"> $("#survey").data("eligible",1); </script>';`

Comment: See my HTML/PHP snippet above.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting your snippet, but it looks like in your code, the php that sets the value of `$eligible` (and subsequently `eligible`) is in the same file as the form, which isn't and can't be the case for me. For me there are 3 files: 1. the html form (which is a php file), 2. the data processor (php script that evaluates the form data and sets `$eligible`/`eligible`), and 3. the page processor (which needs the value of `$eligible`/`eligible`).